# Uso del metodo contains para ArrayList JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist

Necesito comprobar si dos enteros dentro de un ArrayList se encuentran dentro de otra ArrayList y que muestre un mensaje de si se encuentran o no. No consigo hacer que el metodo funcione porque creo que no se utilizarlo correctamente. Adjunto el codigo.

```
public void comprobarBingo(ArrayList<Integer>bolasEx) {
    if (bolasEx.contains(numeros)){
        System.out.println("ES BINGO");
    } else {
        System.out.println("NO ES BINGO");
    }
}
```

Al usar este metodo en el main me da estos resultados.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Bingo b1=new Bingo();
    Carton c1=new Carton();


    for (int i=0;i<=25;i++) {
        b1.extraerBola();
    }


    System.out.println(b1.getBolasExtraidas());
    System.out.println(c1.getNumeros());



    c1.comprobarBingo(b1.getBolasExtraidas());


}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se que hacer, espero puedan resolverme este problema. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: La variable numeros donde la defines e inicializas?

Comment: la defino al principio de la clase y la inicializo en el constructor con un Math.random

Comment: has probado a llamar al método comprobar bingo dentro del bucle for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que estás buscando es el método [List#containsAll(java.util.Collection)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection)) que:

> Devuelve `true` si esta lista sobre la que se invoca contiene todos los elementos de la colección pasada por parámetro.

Por lo que pudes hacer esto:

```
public void comprobarBingo(ArrayList<Integer>bolasEx) {
    if (bolasEx.containsAll(numeros)) {// Solo cambia esta línea
        System.out.println("ES BINGO");
    } else {
        System.out.println("NO ES BINGO");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Segun la documentación de ArrayList.contains() se busca el objeto en si dentro del arraylist, tu estabas buscando los valores del objeto (ArrayList) dentro del ArrayList

Prueba algo asi:

```
 public static void comprobarBingo(ArrayList<Integer>bolasEx) {
    boolean bingo = true; // Inicializamos la variable a true
    for(int i = 0; i < numeros.size(); i++){ //Recorremos el ArrayList de numeros aleatorios
        if (!bolasEx.contains(numeros.get(i))){ //Si el numero por el que estamos pasando no está contenido establecemos bingo a false y salimos del bucle ya que ya no puede ser bingo nunca
            bingo = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (bingo){ // Si bingo es true...
        System.out.println("ES BINGO");
    } else { // Si bingo es false...
        System.out.println("NO ES BINGO");
    }

}
```

Comment: Si, esto resolvió el problema, muchas gracias.

Comment: De nada! para eso estamos!

Comment: Perdón si es molestia, pero ¿podrías explicarme un poco el contenido del bucle for?.

Comment: Edito la respuesta para incluir comentarios, un momento

Comment: Listo, ya la tienes comentada

Comment: Muchas gracias buen hombre.